# angularjs static resources not load in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

i want to use angular in spring mvc application. all angular resources are static and import like this format :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/angularjs.min.js" />"></script> // not load
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/styles.css"/>"> // this load
```

while all other resources like css/js file import in this way too with out any problem load in jsp page and run correctly.but just angular resources not load in pages. angular resources load in html file correctly. what is my problem?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: @mohamedrias,  this error:  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?  and    "GET http://localhost:8083/resources/js/angular.min.js.map 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: can you paste the code in your angular code? it's relaetd to some dependency mentioned in your module

Comment: In case you are using ngRoute, include that file and add it as dependency in your app module

Comment: @mohamedrias i add " angular.min.js.map " but this error is occur: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…tp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8083%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fangularjs.min.js%3A18%3A170)

Comment: angular.min.js.map is not required. It's something related to your angular js code. Not the angular.js library. Because i see that the angularjs library has correctly loaded that's why you are getting that exception from the library.